# Unable to load bukkit-plugin (INVOKESPECIAL/STATIC)

Tags: eclipse, minecraft, bukkit

UPD: Problem was solved. Thanks.
https://github.com/CyberdyneCC/Thermos/issues/498#issuecomment-247083549

Please, help me with this problem.
I compile minecraft bukkit plugin for version 1.7.10 named Spark. Compilation is successful but i can`t load this.
Server core: Thermos 1.7.10.

Full stacktrace:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.lucko.spark.bukkit.BukkitSparkPlugin'
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:191) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:145) ~[JavaPluginLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:334) ~[SimplePluginManager.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:256) [SimplePluginManager.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:343) [CraftServer.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.SaveHandler.initBukkitData(SaveHandler.java:462) [ayq.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.SaveHandler.func_75757_d(SaveHandler.java:138) [ayq.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.World.<init>(World.java:374) [ahb.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.<init>(WorldServer.java:162) [mt.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71247_a(MinecraftServer.java:375) [MinecraftServer.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71197_b(DedicatedServer.java:337) [lt.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:643) [MinecraftServer.class:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to remap class me.lucko.spark.bukkit.BukkitSparkPlugin
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.remappedFindClass(PluginClassLoader.java:534) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:455) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:211) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:189) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INVOKESPECIAL/STATIC on interfaces require ASM 5
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(Unknown Source) ~[asm-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) ~[asm-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source) ~[asm-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[asm-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[asm-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at net.md_5.specialsource.JarRemapper.remapClassFile(JarRemapper.java:246) ~[JarRemapper.class:?]
    at net.md_5.specialsource.JarRemapper.remapClassFile(JarRemapper.java:232) ~[JarRemapper.class:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.remappedFindClass(PluginClassLoader.java:499) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:455) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:211) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:189) ~[PluginClassLoader.class:1.7.10-1614.58]
    ... 12 more
```

Compilation was with using Eclipse IDE.
Class me.lucko.spark.bukkit.BukkitSparkPlugin source:

```
package me.lucko.spark.bukkit;

import me.lucko.spark.bukkit.placeholder.SparkMVdWPlaceholders;
import me.lucko.spark.bukkit.placeholder.SparkPlaceholderApi;
import me.lucko.spark.common.SparkPlatform;
import me.lucko.spark.common.SparkPlugin;
import me.lucko.spark.common.sampler.ThreadDumper;
import me.lucko.spark.common.sampler.TickCounter;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class BukkitSparkPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements SparkPlugin {

    private CommandExecutor tpsCommand = null;
    private SparkPlatform platform;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.platform = new SparkPlatform(this);
        this.platform.enable();

        // override Spigot's TPS command with our own.
        if (getConfig().getBoolean("override-tps-command", true)) {
            this.tpsCommand = (sender, command, label, args) -> {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("spark") && !sender.hasPermission("spark.tps") && !sender.hasPermission("bukkit.command.tps")) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You do not have permission to use this command.");
                    return true;
                }

                BukkitCommandSender s = new BukkitCommandSender(sender) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                this.platform.executeCommand(s, new String[]{"tps"});
                return true;
            };
            CommandMapUtil.registerCommand(this, this.tpsCommand, "tps");
        }

        if (getServer().getPluginManager().isPluginEnabled("PlaceholderAPI")) {
            new SparkPlaceholderApi(this, this.platform);
            getLogger().info("Registered PlaceholderAPI placeholders");
        }
        if (getServer().getPluginManager().isPluginEnabled("MVdWPlaceholderAPI")) {
            new SparkMVdWPlaceholders(this, this.platform);
            getLogger().info("Registered MVdWPlaceholderAPI placeholders");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        this.platform.disable();
        if (this.tpsCommand != null) {
            CommandMapUtil.unregisterCommand(this.tpsCommand);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        this.platform.executeCommand(new BukkitCommandSender(sender), args);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> onTabComplete(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
        return this.platform.tabCompleteCommand(new BukkitCommandSender(sender), args);
    }

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
        return getDescription().getVersion();
    }

    @Override
    public Path getPluginDirectory() {
        return getDataFolder().toPath();
    }

    @Override
    public String getCommandName() {
        return "spark";
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<BukkitCommandSender> getSendersWithPermission(String permission) {
        return Stream.concat(
                getServer().getOnlinePlayers().stream().filter(player -> player.hasPermission(permission)),
                Stream.of(getServer().getConsoleSender())
        ).map(BukkitCommandSender::new);
    }

    @Override
    public void executeAsync(Runnable task) {
        getServer().getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(BukkitSparkPlugin.this, task);
    }

    @Override
    public ThreadDumper getDefaultThreadDumper() {
        return new ThreadDumper.Specific(new long[]{Thread.currentThread().getId()});
    }

    @Override
    public TickCounter createTickCounter() {
        return new BukkitTickCounter(this);
    }
}
```

What could be the problem and how to solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is on your plugin.yml file. On this file you must specify the main class of your plugin so that then Bukkit/Spigot/Paper know where to point when the plugin is enabled. Could you please post the plugin.yml file?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code / plugin.yml. The error is caused by the Bukkit Server not finding your main class. Open the .jar file of your plugin with 7-zip or Winrar and see if the class is really in the .jar file. Also, how do you export, via Maven? If that's the case the error may be on your pom.xml.